# XPath: select trs between trs with specific child

Tags: html, xpath

i cant get it.

I have a web page looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td attr="somevalue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td attr="somevalue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td attr="somevalue"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, i need to select all tr's between tr's with child td with attr (td[@*]), or after such tr if it is the last.

Comment: Based on your example, this is equivalent to selecting all TRs where the [first?] TD does _not_ have the attribute.  If that's not what you mean, provide clearer rules and update your example to match.

Comment: How can something be after the last of something?

Comment: @JimGarrison i want to get 3 blocks of td's: between 1st and 2nd td with attr, between 2nd and 3rd, and after the 3rd td with attr.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just get all the td's that don't have the attr "somevalue"?

```
"//td[not(@attr='somevalue')]"
```